# GRUB2 : zero numpad key not works in FR

Tags: debian, grub2, keyboard

With Linux Debian Buster, I [set a password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) for GRUB2 (version 2.02) but I can not use entirely the numpad keys for typing the user nor the password. When I press **0** (zero) from the numpad I obtain `Unknown key 0x62` but the other numpad keys work.

I observed the same from GRUB shell (from Grub menu press C key to switch to command line) I can press other numpad keys without error. Only the zero numpad key triggers this message...

What is wrong ?

---

I just realized that the probable cause for this problem is the creation of the `/boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb` file.

At the same time that protect GRUB with password I wanted to make the GRUB shell more convenient to use with an `AZERTY` keyboard (I'm French).

So following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946419/how-to-change-grub2-keylayout-on-samsung-laptop) I created this file with this command (I translated the returned french messages in english) :

```
root@host:~# ckbcomp fr | grub-mklayout -o /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb
Unknown Meta_Tab key identifier
Unknown Meta_Tab key identifier
Unknown key code 0x54
Unknown key code 0x65
Unknown key code 0x7f
```

The command succeeds but returns messages that some key codes are unknown (messages that I ignored by telling myself that it must be normal).

It looks strangely like the problem observed, even if the `0x62` code reported by GRUB (see above) is not part of it but must be related.

To be convinced, I removed the French GRUB support and from the GRUB shell I tested the following numpad keys :

`0123456789/*-+`

Who gives no error this time.

So the problem comes from the creation of fr.gkb but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

---

I discovered that `ckbcomp fr` displays an organised flow that I do not know how to decrypt but which seems OK (no error) and `ckbcomp fr` read in fact the keyboard file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` but I do not know how to modify this file which seems more accessible to me that the `ckbcomp` flow.

Comment: On my machine, I can select NUMPAD ON in the BIOS.

Comment: In my case nothing to do with BIOS it is enabled because I can press other numpad keys without error. I suspect a bug and I isolated the problem in typing **123456789/*-+0** from GRUB shell (from Grub menu press **C** key to switch to command line). Only the **0** (zero) numpad key triggers this message...

Comment: Nobody to help me ?